# Efficient algorithm for matching multiple regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I have a system where the users need to configure a list of patterns, and then I need to apply those patterns to input data and determine which one matched.

Currently, the patterns are defined using regular expressions R1, R2, .. Rn, and I iterate over them linearly to see which one matches.

Is there a more efficient way?

I can concatenate them into one massive compound regex like `(?<r1>R1)|(?<r2>R2)|..|(?<rn>Rn)`, apply it, and then resolve which one matched by the capture group, but I doubt that would be more efficient (or will it?).

Is there some other algorithm? Something like a Radix tree but for regular expressions, or regular expression-like patterns? I don't have to support the full regex syntax if it simplifies the problem, but I do need the patterns to at least have wildcard support, and be reasonably easily describable in a config file.

If a thirdparty implementation is available, that would be best.

So far, I found https://github.com/osense/retrie, but it's in Erlang and I don't get it :)

Comment: In my regex experience in perl and python one big concatenated regex will be faster than some kind of for loop.  The best way to know for sure though is to try both, and time it.  Look into pre compiling your regex too, that will help.

Comment: I suggest you try it, but one `Pattern.compile(regex)` using a concat I would assume is fastest. For some simple cases, other structures might be better, but a general case is most likely best does as a regex.

Comment: @sniperd: Bad advice. One big concatenated pattern may be faster only with specific conditions (if optimizations are possible before the "normal walk" of the regex engine, if the string is short or if succeeding positions are at the beginning...), otherwise it depends on the string size (and with an alternation with many branches, the cost will be heavy). The problem with this design is that the regex engine must test all branches for each position that doesn't match. Note also that with interpreted script languages, the cost of a for loop is different.

Comment: Are the patterns really regular expressions? If so, are there any limitations on the regular expression features you allow/care about?

Comment: @rici they are currently fairly simple regular expressions. Beside exact strings, I have things like `.*text.*`, `text.+`, `[a-z]{32,}\.ext`, `text1|text2`.

Comment: In that case, you could use [JFlex](http://jflex.de/manual.html) to build a lexer at compile time, or you could dynamically use JFlex to produce a lexer and then compile and load it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte hence the "The best way to know for sure though is to try both, and time it." :)